# Como puedo usar el jquery ui autocomplete? usando otro input como valor a consultar

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, jquery-ui

Sobre el tema, tengo un input que tiene la id que necesito y quisera que recueprar de ese input y ejecutar el autocomplete para que me traiga los datos y autcompletar lo demas, solo que esa parte no me suena como realizarlo ya que con ui directamente agarra la de ese input

### edit

1. Tienes un input con una ID. 2) Tienes otro input con autocompletar. 3) El autocompletar depende de los datos del 1er input como del segundo.
   este era lo que queria exponer

php autcomplete

```
public function autocompleteData($id)
   {
      $returnData = array();
      $valor = $this->request->getGet('term');
      $compra = $this->compras->obtenerautocomplete($id);
      if (!empty($compra)) {
         foreach ($compra as $row) {
            $data['id_facc'] = $row['id'];
            $data['total'] = $row['total'];
            $data['label'] = $row['folio']. ' - ' . $row['nombre_proveedor'];
            $data['saldo'] = $row['saldo'];
            $data['folio'] = $row['folio'];
            array_push($returnData, $data);
         }
      } else {
         $data['error'] = 'desastre';
         array_push($returnData, $data);
      }
      echo json_encode($returnData);
   }
```

--
script

```
$(function() {
        $("#facc").autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/compras/compras/autocompleteData",
            minLength: 0,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#facc").val(ui.item.folio);
                $("#saldo").val(ui.item.saldo);
                $("#ruc").val(ui.item.ruc);
                $("#idfacc").val(ui.item.id_facc);

            }
        });

    });
```

input `introducir el código aquí`

```
<input class="form-control" id="facc" name="facc" type="text" placeholder="elija la factura  y presiona enter" onkeyup="agregarFactura(evnt, this.value , document.getElementById('monto').value,<?php echo $id_temppagos; ?>)" required />
```

el input con la id que me falta y ya se autocompleto antes

```
 <input type="hidden" id="id_proveedor" name="id_proveedor" class="form-control" />
```

Saludos

Comment: No entendí el problema. Que es lo que quieres hacer y que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: @Yussef me pregunto lo mismo ... esta como rara la pregunta... pero leyendo todo el contexto creo que no le esta funcionando el `autocomplete` esperemos a ver que nos detalla antes de dar una solucion...

Comment: viste que tengo el valor que quiero que lleve el autocomplete en otra  input que esta oculta, que se rellena antes y en esta quisiera que la variable term que manda el autocomplete me gustaria que llevara ese valor y no el valor que escribo en la input

Comment: Si ya tienes ID del proveedor en el arreglo, solo te falta agregar una línea cuando se selecciona el elemento: `$("#id_proveedor").val(ui.id);`

Comment: no, o sea debo enviar esa ese valor, en el arreglo vuelve las facturas relacionadas con ese proveedor desde la consulta interna que espera ese valor del proveedor, legalmente se que me falta mucho para entender como funciona el autocomplete pero me gustaria ir modificando el valor del term que envia por otro input , esa parte lo que me faltaria, si falta mas datos puedo poner todo el codigo ,muy kilombo nomas es

Comment: Creo que ya entendí. 1) Tienes un input con una ID. 2) Tienes otro input con autocompletar. 3) El autocompletar depende de los datos del 1er input como del segundo. Eso?

Comment: siiiiiiiiiiii, asi mismo, como podria acudir a esa input, o como deberia hacerlo? soy muynovato por eso la preguntota que pareceria facil pero no alcanza mi cabeza jejeje

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca el PHP compras/compras/autocompleteData, para ver que estas recibiendo ahí

Comment: Listo, Necesitas la consulta?